# segfault on first access to map with [] operator

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I'm running into a problem adding an element to a map linking strings to a custom class Node.
I saw no reason why the problem could have been caused by static initialization order, but wrapped the map in a function to test, and got the same results as before. I have the following code in three files:

In node.h:

```
class Node
{
    public:
        const std::string name;
        Node (){};
        Node (std::string name, double x, double y);
        Node (const Node& b);
};

std::map<std:: string, Node>& nodeMap();
```

In node.cpp:

```
map<string,Node>& nodeMap()
{
    static map<string,Node>* temp = new map<string, Node>();
    return *temp;
}
Node::Node (std::string name, double x, double y):name(name)
{
    nodeMap()[name]=*this;
}
```

And in main.cpp I initialize with:

```
itoa(i,i_str,10);
Node nI (i_str,rand(),rand());
```

The program compiles fine, but when it runs it crashes on `nodeMap()[name]=*this`, and the debugger returns

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   In ntdll!LdrWx86FormatVirtualImage () (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)

I'm sure I'm probably missing something obvious - I'm relatively new to c++ - but can't figure out where my error is.

Comment: Please can you form this into a self-contained compilable example?  (See http://sscce.org).

Comment: What is the value of `i` and `i_str`? And how you've declare them? Post that part of code as well.

Comment: Debug to see where it is actually segfaulting...use "step into" or examine the stack trace.  I'm wondering about copy constructor/assignment operator.  BTW, having Node essentially manage its container map seems like a bad idea.

Comment: As it is, your code does not compile. Node is not assignable because of the const member. Your `operator=` might be relevant too.

Comment: Problem was due to attempting to assign instance of node to the map while still in the constructor.

Thank you for the help - sorry for not posting a compilable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about it. But you have used the instance of Node before its constructor returns.

```
Node::Node (std::string name, double x, double y):name(name) // This is the constructor!
{ 
    nodeMap()[name]=*this; // You have tried to assign the current instance to map entry. NB: instance of Node is not finalized.
}
```

You should write constructor like

```
Node::Node (std::string name, double x, double y):name(name) // This is the constructor!
{ 
}
```

then in your main

```
Node nI(i_str, rand(), rand());
nodeMap()[nI.name]=nI;
```

Comment: `*this` should be entirely valid in a constructor body (otherwise you couldn't access any members).